# Cannot access any SharePoint sites and Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, domain

I am running SharePoint Server 2016 on two separate servers: one application server and one database server. I have created a number of sites in a site-collection. Recently today, I am not able to access these sites as well as the Central Administration. I have not made any configuration changes to the servers since this happened. I received the below error message:

**This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2016  Products.**

I tried the below solutions which I found on the internet with no luck:

- Restarted both SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and SQL Server Agent
  (MSSQLSERVER) services (they were already running before I restarted them).
- I checked the domain accounts which some SQL Server services and SharePoint
  services run as and found that the current password is still valid (these account passwords have been set to never expire in Active Directory).
- I restarted the SharePoint application server and the database server
  with no luck.

What could be the cause of the above error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The SharePoint application server's default gateway was set to a router which did not have a route to the domain controller where the SharePoint users are located. Changing the default gateway to the router which has a route to the domain controller solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message the issue may caused by Everyone and All Users groups were not added in "Access this computer from network" policy on SQL Server which was causing accounts (which were not part of Local Admin group on SQL server) unable to access SQL server from SharePoint server. By default, Everyone and All Users groups should be part of this policy on both SQL and SharePoint servers , you could check if someone has removed them and left only Local Administrators group in there . If no , add Everyone and All Users group in "Access this computer from the network" policy on SQL Server and ran group policy update which allowed all users to be able to access SQL from SharePoint server .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single server farm then please check SQL Server service may be stopped. On SQL Server box restart SQL Server service.

If you are using two or more SQL Servers with High Availability then on any SQL Server box open Failover Cluster Manager and check the status of cluster and each node and act per need.